# Linker command failed: duplicate symbol _applicationFrame

Tags: ios5, xcode4.3, linker-errors

I am working on a universal application, but it gives linker error after adding a new class `[CallScreenViewController]`:

> duplicate symbol _applicationFrame in /Users/msdk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UniversalTest-cxggvelerfpnpgfzfehcwddjtfkd/Build/Intermediates/UniversalTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/UniversalTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/ChatScreenViewController.o and /Users/msdk/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/UniversalTest-cxggvelerfpnpgfzfehcwddjtfkd/Build/Intermediates/UniversalTest.build/Debug-iphoneos/UniversalTest.build/Objects-normal/armv7/CallScreenViewController.o for architecture armv7
>   clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: What is the definition of `applicationFrame`?  Is it in a header that is imported by both `ChatScreenViewController` and `CallScreenViewController`?

Comment: CGRect applicationFrame; 
No. it's not imported by both ChatScreenViewController & CallScreenViewController but declare in both .m file

Comment: If it's defined as an instance variable, that should be OK.  If you've defined it with global scope, that's a problem.

Comment: yap you are right.... :)
It's working now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solve the problem.
CGRect applicationFrame is the cause for linker error. because it's declare globally both in  ChatScreenViewController & CallScreenViewController.
Thanks Phillip :)